# How do you create a list with a single value in R?

Tags: r

How do you create a list with a single value in R?
For example, I want a list of 50 zeros.
What is the easiest way to define this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How is a list of 50 zeros ~ a list with a single value?

Try this:

```
list(rep(0, 50))
```

Or if you want a list with fifty separate elements of zeros, you can do this:

```
as.list(rep(0, 50))
```

Comment: `as.list` is what you want if you're trying to make a vector that you can bind to a data.frame

Comment: What do i do if i want to have a random repetition created by a variable?
Does it work with strings as well?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
res <- list(rep(0,50))
```

is all you need?